# Why would only ♦ moderators be "Interested in the status of tasks you've already reviewed?"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, moderator-tools

Most of you know what an empty review queue looks like:

[image]

However, ♦ moderators see something different:

[image]

> Interested in the status of tasks you've already reviewed? View your complete review history, including skipped items.

The link leads to your personal review history (in my case, https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/close/history?userId=7297). Why is this link only included for ♦ moderators?

I *suspect* that the intention here is that regular users can click the 'history' tab to see their personal history (which excludes skipped items by default); ♦ moderators see the entire review queue history (for all users) and would need to scroll down to a link 'my review history'. However, 10k users can also [review reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and see the full history (the only difference is that they can't see other users' skipped items, and have no means to investigate a single user's review history). That privilege has been added later and perhaps no one realized that this would be one of the consequences.

Still, it would make more sense to me if *all* users would see that link. Or am I missing something?

Comment: *Most of you know what an empty review queue looks like*  ... not if you're living in the Close Vote Queue on SO ...

Comment: Heh, the first draft of my question started with "All of you know ..." but that would exclude non-privileged users as well.

Comment: You know nothing, Jon Snow...